# Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #<ActiveStorage::VariantWithRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix, actiontext

According to documentation I added `action_text/trix` to my rails app. And when I update a content. It shows me following errors. Any idea?

```
Showing /home/dell/code/tm/app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb where line #3 raised:

Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #<ActiveStorage::VariantWithRecord:0x0000559255e1be40 @blob=#<ActiveStorage::Blob id: 12, key: "n48e43looijem16cdq5d48sqhu4d", filename: "Screenshot from 2021-08-28 17-10-25.png", content_type: "image/png", metadata: {}, service_name: "local", byte_size: 93757, checksum: "up8PwkoYwf+Y6NTRJvbAUA==", created_at: "2021-08-29 12:13:04.912555000 +0800">, @variation=#<ActiveStorage::Variation:0x0000559255e248d8 @transformations={:format=>"png", :resize_to_limit=>[1024, 768]}>>
Did you mean?  to_yaml

ActionView::Template::Error (Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #<ActiveStorage::VariantWithRecord:0x0000559255e1be40 @blob=#<ActiveStorage::Blob id: 12, key: "n48e43looijem16cdq5d48sqhu4d", filename: "Screenshot from 2021-08-28 17-10-25.png", content_type: "image/png", metadata: {}, service_name: "local", byte_size: 93757, checksum: "up8PwkoYwf+Y6NTRJvbAUA==", created_at: "2021-08-29 12:13:04.912555000 +0800">, @variation=#<ActiveStorage::Variation:0x0000559255e248d8 @transformations={:format=>"png", :resize_to_limit=>[1024, 768]}>>
Did you mean?  to_yaml):
    1: <figure class="attachment attachment--<%= blob.representable? ? "preview" : "file" %> attachment--<%= blob.filename.extension %>">
    2:   <% if blob.representable? %>
    3:     <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]) %>
    4:   <% end %>
    5: 
    6:   <figcaption class="attachment__caption">
  
app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb:3
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3', '>= 6.1.3.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
gem 'devise'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'pagy', '~> 3.5'
gem 'money-rails', '~>1.12'
gem "view_component", require: "view_component/engine"

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

gem 'metka', '~> 2.3.1'
gem 'ransack', '~> 2.4.2'
gem 'country_select', '~> 6.0'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 6.0.0'
```

My model:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord

  has_rich_text :body

end
```

And migration:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :slug

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <%= f.label :body, class: 'form-label required' %>
      <%= f.rich_text_area :body %>
      <%= display_error_messages(@resource, 'body') %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

According to documentation I didn't add `body` column to `pages` tables.
Any idea? Am I miss something?

**UPDATE:**
I addeg `gem 'image_processing'` to `Gemfile`. But result is the same :(

**UPDATE 2:** I also installed `imagemagick` in my Ubuntu.

**UPDATE 3**: And it's not work only in `update` action.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution.

I was writing a Ruby Engine / Ruby Plugin as a gem, and apparently ActiveStorage was unable to figure out the polymorphic routing thanks to the namespacing.

I had to change "views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb" as follows:

```
- <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]) %>
+ <%= image_tag main_app.url_for(blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ])) %>
```

Thanks @rbngzlv for the answer on Github.

Comment: thank you! I was going crazy trying to figure this out, knew it had to do with it being an engine but wasn't sure what. This change was in the main app or from the engine?

Comment: Underrated comment. I was hitting the same issue on Rails 7 and this fixed it for me! Still works in 2024...

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `bin/rails action_text:install` and installed the migrations? And also activestorage?

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#installation There you can find how do do it and it also links to activestorage for embdedded attachments.